# Реализация линейной регрессии

Tags: машинное-обучение, регрессия

При реализации линейной регрессии возникла проблема: при градиентном спуске loss увеличивается причем на несколько порядков за раз. Loss - MSE, градиентный спуск - обычный. В качестве датасета выбрал [The California housing dataset](https://inria.github.io/scikit-learn-mooc/python_scripts/datasets_california_housing.html) . При написании кода опирался на [статью](https://ml-handbook.ru/chapters/linear_models/intro). Чтобы отдельно не работать со смещением, заранее добавил столбец из 1 в начало матрицы признаков.
Код класса

```
class LinearRegression():

  w = None
  alpha = None

  def __init__(self, lr, E=20):
    self.lr = lr
    self.w = np.zeros(X.shape[1] + 1)
    self.E = E

  def loss(self, X, y):
    return np.sum((X @ self.w - y) ** 2) / X.shape[0]

  def grad(self, X, y):
    grad_basic = 2 * np.transpose(X) @ (X @ self.w - y) / X.shape[0]   
    assert grad_basic.shape == (X.shape[1],) , "Градиенты должны быть столбцом из k_features + 1 элементов"
    return grad_basic

  def sgd(self, X, y, E=20):
    self.loss_arr = [self.loss(X, y)]
    for _ in tqdm(range(E)):
      if abs(self.loss_arr[-1]) < 0.1:
        break
      self.w -= self.lr * self.grad(X, y)
      self.loss_arr.append(self.loss(X, y))

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self.sgd(X, y, self.E)

  def get_params(self):
    return self.w

  def get_loss(self):
    return self.loss_arr

  def predict(self, X):
    return X.dot(self.w)
```

Вот так ведет себя loss: 5.637, 288906709850, 3.250e+22...

При этом аналитически решение находится верно. Его и полный код регрессии можно найти в [ноутбуке](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EBAIrLuzvh_4Kb5_V3GA2e4NusNgB0nv?usp=sharing). Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Увеличение ошибки может говорить о том, что при градиентном спуске вы идете не в том направлении -  точнее говоря, идете в сторону увеличения ошибки, а не уменьшения. Проверяйте, где у вас в коде стоит не тот знак.

Comment: Что-то там смена знака не помогает. И уменьшение `lr`. Там какой-то прям "взрыв градиентов" в любом случае, явно что-то с формулами кардинально не то )

Comment: Перепроверил все знаки, вынес отдельно bias и заменил матричную формулу на циклы, как в этой [статье](https://ml-cheatsheet-russian.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/linear_regression.html), но результат тот же. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Уважаемый  CrazyElf дал вторую подсказку "что-то с формулами кардинально не то".  Проверяйте. . Возьмите не реальный, а синтетический пример, посчитайте несколько шагов вручную, потом запустите свой код и сравнивайте результаты. Это и есть отладка.  Профессия разработчика - это 20% времени написание кода, а 80% -  его отладка. Вот и совершенствуйте этот навык. Пригодиться.